# Организовать и вывести на экран символьный массив, заполнив его символами, полученными преобразованиями чисел массива В в символы

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
    program gh;

    const
      n = 21;

    var
      c, a: array[1..n] of byte; 
      m, x, i, j, k: integer;

    begin
      randomize; 
      for i := 1 to n do 
        c[i] := random(9); 
      for i := 1 to n do 
      begin
        write(c[i]:4); 
      end; 
      writeln; 
      k := (n div 2); 
      for i := 2 to k do 
      begin
        x := c[i]; 
        j := i - 1; 
        while ((j > 0) and (x < c[j])) do 
        begin
          c[j + 1] := c[j]; 
          j := j - 1; 
        end; 
        c[j + 1] := x; 
      end; 
      for i := 1 to k do 
      begin
        write(c[i]:4); 
      end; 
      writeln; 
      m := ((n div 2) + 1); 
      for i := ((n div 2) + 2) to n do 
      begin
        x := c[i]; 
        j := i - 1; 
        while ((j > 0) and (x > c[j])) do 
        begin
          c[j + 1] := c[j]; 
          j := j - 1; 
        end; 
        c[j + 1] := x; 
      end; 
      for i := ((n div 2) + 2) to n do 
      begin
        write(c[i]:4); end; 
      writeln; 
      a := chr(a[i]);
      a := c;
      writeln(c[i]);
```

Comment: а где сам вопрос?

Comment: я просто не знаю как сделать преобразование